# How to use TrueCrypt with SkyDrive?

Tags: windows-7, truecrypt, onedrive

Dropbox handles TrueCrypt containers very nicely.  When I update the TrueCrypt container then dismount it, Dropbox syncs only the modifications.  Just what I wanted :)

SkyDrive on the other hand, when I update the TrueCrypt container then dismount it, SkyDrive knows that the container has changed as the little indicator starting moving, but nothing actually gets synced to my SkyDrive. :(

I did read on a different forum about changing a preference in TrueCrypt's to **not** preserve the modification timestamp of the file container.  When I did this, then updated a container and dismounted it, SkyDrive noticed the modification, but synced the whole blasted container!  Not just the modifications like Dropbox did :(

Am I doing something incorrect or is there a setting within SkyDrive to make it act like Dropbox?  It would be really nice to use SkyDrive as I have 25GB of space on SkyDrive compared to 2GB on Dropbox...

Thanks,

Comment: As far as I can tell, SkyDrive probably works the same way as many other Microsoft products (including, for example, FileStream in SQL Server), where a change in a file means re-uploading. If I were designing a system for most people to use that's built into Windows (I see that happening for Windows 8), replacing the whole file is "good enough".

Comment: That is typical Microsoft at time "good enough".  My TrueCrypt container is 500MB so replacing the whole file is painful at times...  The SkyDrive windows application is still in beta so maybe they will change it soon to be more like Dropbox.

Comment: Typical, yes. It is often "good enough" to satisfy "most" users, especially considering the size and technical ability of their user base, and economics of adding features for the more technical users.

Answer (score 4):

Skydrive (and many other similar services, including Google Drive) do not have the ability to do blockwise synchronization -- their smallest units are files. You are, unfortunately, out of luck if you are tied to both SkyDrive and TrueCrypt.

A workaround may be to switch from TruCrypt to encfs when using SkyDrive -- instead of encrypting an entire partition/imagefile like TrueCrypt, encfs works on files and directories (but still provides access via a separate drive letter on Windows or a separate mountpoint in *ix). The encryption is sound, but naturally you are making a tradeoff -- while Skydrive will not be able to discern the contents of your files (or their filenames), the way encfs works necessarily leaks information about the size of your files (and the approximate length of your filenames).

I have been using http://members.ferrara.linux.it/freddy77/encfs.html on Windows with Google Drive for a while without issue. While you still don't get intrafile-syncing, if the actual files you currently keep within your TrueCrypt-volume are small(ish), only the ones you actually change will be synced.

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox has support for delta encoding technology as described in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29). SkyDrive does not have this technology, so it always sends whole file. You can try other cloud storage providers which have support for delta encoding.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is really old, but since I found it on a Google search perhaps someone else might find this helpful.  What I did to get this to work is create a TrueCrypt container, then create a batch file in my Windows startup directory that specifies the file to mount and what drive to mount it as via command line switches.  Then, add a GOTO loop until it can find a particular text file (D:\mounted.txt for example) and only then launch OneDrive.

To get this to work, you have to turn off "Automatically Start with Windows" in the OneDrive settings.

My batch file looks like this, obviously you'll need to change values to suit your paths and file names.  You can also launch applications that exist solely inside the TrueCrypt volume as well.

```
@echo off
echo Checking for successful mount.
if exist f:\mounted.txt goto drivemounted
"C:\Program Files\TrueCrypt\TrueCrypt.exe" /v "C:\Users\<username>\Archive.tc" /ld /a /q
echo Truecrypt executed.

:checkmount
if exist D:\mounted.txt (
    goto drivemounted
) else (
    goto checkmount
)

:drivemounted
echo Success.  Starting OneDrive
start C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\OneDrive\OneDrive.exe
echo Finished.
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by setting in TrueCrypt or VeraCrypt, **NOT** to "Preserve modification timestamp of file containers". Each time the container is modified inside, the container timestamp is updated and Dropbox or OneDrive will see this as a file change and resync the file.

[image: Preserve modification timestamp of file containers]